# new to php mark up, why is this standard practice

Tags: php, if-statement

Ok so im new to php but slowly getting to understand it. I have one question though. In these to examples below I am able to get both to work with different markup. One has { } in it and one does not. Why is this so? Can someone please explain.

With

```
<?php
    $guess = 7;
    $number = 7;

    if ( $guess < $number ){
    echo "Too low!";
    }elseif ($guess > $number){
    echo "Too high!";
    }else {
    echo "You win!";
    }

  ?>
```

With-out

```
<?php
    $guess = 7;
    $number = 7;

    if ( $guess < $number )
    echo "Too low!";
    elseif ($guess > $number)
    echo "Too high!";
    else 
    echo "You win!";

  ?>
```

Comment: Coding standards. The short *if* notations also exist in other languages (e.g. C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unique to PHP, it is a conditional shorthand. If you omit the `{` and `}` from an if statement then only the next line of code is considered to be inside (until `;` is seen).

Personally it makes more sense to me like this:

```
<?php
    $guess = 7;
    $number = 7;

    if ($guess < $number) echo "Too low!";
    elseif ($guess > $number) echo "Too high!";
    else echo "You win!";
?>
```

Comment: There's a space between `else` and `if` in PHP and I can't edit your post for one character...

Comment: You actually _can_ use elseif, although it's nonstandard
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Should be valid... http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php I copy / pasted his code from above

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard as languages go.  Essentially, you can only omit the brackets if there is **one** line after the `if` statement.  If there is more than one, you'll get an error.

Comment: You will get an error if there are an *elseif* or an *else* branch. But if there are none, you won't get any syntax errors and that can lead to bugs.

Comment: Are you talking about just a plain if statement?

Comment: There are actually three cases: `if(a) expr1; exprX;`, `if(a) expr1; else if (b) expr2; exprX;` and `else expr1; exprX;`. In each case, *exprX* is meant to be inside the branch, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the curly brackets are advisable (similar syntax is used in a number of languages, such as Java, C++, Javascript, etc.).

- Without the brackets it will run the code as part of the block until it gets to a semicolon. This can be used as a shorthand when you only want to run a single line of code in a block. However, adding a second line will break your code and can be difficult to debug since it generally won't produce an error. For example:

  ```
  $b = "hello";
  if ($foo)
      $a = "hello";
      $b = "goodbye";
  ```

  In this case, $b will always equal "goodbye" but it's perfectly valid code.
- With the brackets it will run everything inside there.

Comment: Your example will yield a syntax error: http://ideone.com/Ac16H1

Comment: Yep. Noticed that at the same time you did; fixed. That's what I get for trying to rush in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept that you can found in a lot of languages: you can omit the braces if you have only one statement in your block. A block is even one statement, so these codes are equivalent:

```
for(...)
    if($b)
        $res = true;


for(...) {
    if($b) {
        $res = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is because your it contain only one line statement after `if` and in that case either you group them into braces or not it doesn't matter. as interpreter will will understand it without any problem.**

*Its just the shortcut when we have only one statement in `if`.*

Whereas when we have many statements to be covered within `if` we need { } to denote that the all have to be executed if this condition occurs.

Eg:

```
while()
if()
statement 1;
else
statement 2;
```

they all will work perfectly fine..

but when it get a condition like;

```
while()
if()
statement 1;
statement ABC;
Statement DEF;
else
statement 2;
```

Then it will show an error !

So in order to make the error fly ;)

Just use  brackets :

```
 while() {
if() {
statement 1;
statement ABC;
Statement DEF;
 } else {
statement 2; }
```

**OR** you can also use **if,endif**

Eg

```
  while() :
if() :
statement 1;
statement ABC;
Statement DEF;

else :
statement 2;

 endif;
endwhile;
```